# PHP IF else on Time

Tags: php, if-statement, strtotime

```
$today=date("d");       # today
$startdate="14";        # start of advent 14th/13th
$enddate="25";          # end of advent 24th/25th
//strtomtime
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Christmas Advant Calendar</title></head><body>

<div class="adventframework">

    <?php
        /*$i=$startdate;
        while($i<=$enddate)
        {
            echo "<div class='datebox " . $i . "' id='" . $i ."'>";
            echo "Today is the " . $i . "";
            echo "</div>";
            $i++;
        }*/ 

        if ($startdate==$today){
            echo 'today and start date match';
        }
```

The problem is that today is `01` and yet the script echos: `today and start date match` when `$startdate` is 14 - I am supposed to use strtotime I here; where does it go?

Comment: Not homework. If it was I would'nt tell you. People on here know im Front end from an ASP background and I am gradually learning PHP. Which I enjoy.

Comment: have you tried to print $today to see what it prints?

Comment: prints 01 as mentioned several times up and down.

Comment: It works fine for me, which leads me to believe that there is some quirky behavior from your PHP install.  For reference, I'm using `~ ?> php -v
PHP 5.3.6 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Sep  8 2011 19:34:00)` What version are you running?

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid see my demo/answer - it works fine.

Comment: I think @AndrewKozak you're on to something here.. ive had issues on this server before with time...

Comment: PHP Version 5.0.5

System  Linux lsh505.securepod.com 2.6.33.3 #1 SMP Sun May 9 09:16:45 CEST 2010 i686
Build Date  Sep 8 2005 12:08:50

Comment: Definitely outdated.  Best upgrade to 5.3.x to stay current if you can.  Best of luck!

Comment: Can't all my scripts would fail and this client is on shared hosting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is typecasting.

Try doing

```
if ((int)$startdate == (int)$today)
```

More over set $startdate like:

```
$startdate = 14; //instead of $startdate = "14"
```

Comment: This returns blank as expected. Why INT?

Comment: You can also simplify the current date:  $today = (int)date("j");  You want to use (int) so that you're comparing numbers instead of strings - this will behave more like you are expecting.

Comment: It should return blank (false) because todays day (01) doesn't match $starttime (14)

Comment: Cool. I have always wanted to know that.

Comment: I have always used strtotime and I think with my server PHP build for my client it does not supoprt it aswell as it should

Comment: What I also like about this, is it checks for 01 and 1 as the same - so dates can be 01 or 1... clever.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`strcmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php)

```
if(strcmp($startdate, $today) === 0) { //strings match
    echo 'today and start date match';
}
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/lN90FUSa

Comment: That just echoes today and start date match - the script should compile blank because today is 01

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid one sec ill make a demo

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid see the demo i added to the question. make sure that `$today!=01`

Comment: Thanks I repped you but I think it is a server issue now. As mention by a poster in the first thread of comments in my original question. Thanks Repped your comments too and plus them up!